# How to compress coredump file in Linux

Tags: core-dump, dump

After changing the creation location of the coredump file using the core_pattern file, the coredump is not compressed.

Before changing the content of core_pattern, the content was `|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e`.
At this time, a `lz4` compressed core dump was created in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/`.
After changing the core_pattern to `/app/MyApp/coredump`, the core dump is created correctly in the changed location, but the file is not compressed.

Is this issue related to the issue of not using `systemd-coredump`?
My understanding is that `systemd-coredump` compresses the core dump.

Is there any way to change the core_pattern and still get the core dumps compressed with `lz4`?

Thanks.